# google app script version archiving problem

Tags: google-apps-script, archive

I have a standalone google app script. I have already deployed three versions of it as libraries until now. I have archived the 2. version, because it had some issues. There are some google spreadsheets in the company where we choose this standalone script as a library and when we choose the version of the script we can still choose and use the archived version too. I think it is a bug, is it? Otherwise I don't understand what is the meaning of the archive function then.

I indicated the problem here as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/313078062

Thanks for your help!

Comment: - [Bug Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [List of Issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/566222)

Comment: - [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)